# Where is the default authentication route configured in ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication

I've got an old WebForms-based ASP.NET app that I have upgraded to ASP.NET 4.0 and I want to add some portions of the site that use MVC.  I've successfully done this but the problem is I want to share the old login page.

I used the instructions [**here**](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntegratingASPNETMVC3IntoExistingUpgradedASPNET4WebFormsApplications.aspx) to integrate MVC.

Both parts of the site use the SqlMemberbershipProvider, but even though my web.config is configured to route unauthenticated requests to my "~/Login.aspx" page, they are now getting kicked to "Accounts/Login".

Here's my web config auth entry:

```
<authentication mode="Forms">
  <forms loginUrl="login.aspx" name=".ASPXFORMSAUTH" />
</authentication>
```

Where in the MVC plumbing does it now override that to force it to "Accounts/Login". is this just a "convention" used by MVC?  The upshot is I still want to redirect unauthenticated requests to Login.aspx no matter what the target page/route is.

Mike

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's a [known bug](http://www.asp.net/learn/whitepapers/mvc3-release-notes#0.1__Toc274034230). You may try adding the `loginUrl` app key following to your web.config:

```
<appSettings>
    <add key="loginUrl" value="~/login.aspx" />
<appSettings>
```

Comment: Thanks for the link.  I was knee deep System.Web.Mvc in Reflector when I decided to take a break and post to SO.  Saved me another few hours probably.